# Como coloco uma tag html dentro do código php para formatar o texto que ali está?

Tags: php, echo

Tenho o seguinte código e queria colocar a tag `<font> </font>` por exemplo para formatar o usuário.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    echo "Usuario: ". $_SESSION['usuarioNome'];    
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fecha a tag php, escreve o html normalmente e chama a variável com um echo $nomeVar. No caso, criei um p, e dentro dele adicionei um span para customizar o que for necessário de css.Cor, fonte, margin e etc.

```
<?php
    session_start();

    // atribuí uma variável ao teu _SESSION.
    // Não precisava, só quis reduzir o código de chamada.
    $username = $_SESSION['usuarioNome'];    
?>

<p>
    Olá,
        <span class="user-name">
            <?php
                // Escreve a variável
                echo $username;
            ?>
        </span>
</p>
```

No seu arquivo de css você adiciona a classe adicionada ao span.

```
<style>
    .user-name{ font-weight: bold; }
</style>
```

Ele vai exibir assim:

> Olá, **Hugo**

Comment: Tente colocar uma breve explicação do que você fez e como funciona.

Comment: Pronto @Francisco, documentei.

Answer (score 4):

Junta o HTML a essa string, assim por exemplo:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    echo "<strong>Usuario:</strong> ". $_SESSION['usuarioNome'];    
?>
```

Isso irá aparecer no browser assim:

> **Usuario:** Lauriana